# Why isn't my exception handler firing in Sitecore.mvc.Pipelines?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I am trying to create a nice Exception Message for our public site, thus I am overriding "Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exceptions.ShowAspNetErrorMessage" by modifying my Sitecore.Pipelines config file, like so

```
<mvc.exception patch:source="Pipelines.config">
<processor type="Northwestern.Core.Infrastructure.Pipelines.ExceptionErrorHandler, Northwestern.Core"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
</mvc.exception>
```

and here is my ExceptionErrorHandler code:

```
namespace Northwestern.Core.Infrastructure.Pipelines
{
    public class ExceptionErrorHandler : ExceptionProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(ExceptionArgs args)
        {
            var context = args.ExceptionContext;
            var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
            var exception = context.Exception;

            // Return a 500 status code and execute the custom error page.
            httpContext.Server.ClearError();
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            httpContext.Server.Execute("/Error-Page");
        }

    }
}
```

but, I have placed a breakpoint inside the above code and it never hits my breakpoint

Comment: What kind of exception do you throw to check that your code should be executed? Be aware that not all type of exceptions are handled in mvc.exception pipeline.(e.g. creating of controller will not be handled)

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the pipeline like this :

```
  <pipelines>
      <mvc.exception>
        <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage, Sitecore.Mvc">
          <patch:attribute name="type">Northwestern.Core.Infrastructure.Pipelines.ExceptionErrorHandler, Northwestern.Core</patch:attribute>
        </processor>
      </mvc.exception>
    </pipelines>
```

Comment: Thank you ... this is helpful